# Sequence Convergence trouble

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $a>0$ and $x_1 > 0$, I have the following sequence $$\{x_n\}_{n}^{\infty} = x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(x_{n}^2 + 3a)}{3x_{n}^2 + a}$$ I want to show that this is convergence and find it's limit.

I think I would start off by stating the formal definition of sequence convergence. I could alternatively find a convergent subsequence, but I don't think I know how to do that. That is, For any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$. $L$ would represent what the sequence $x_n$ tends to.

So, our first objective should be to find this $N$. Though, i'm not really sure how to start off on all of this.

Comment: i think use Cauchy criterion for convergence here is better, once you show it converges, replace $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ by $L$ then solve the cubic

Comment: I think you need to consider it in 3 cases: $x_1^2=a ,x_1^2<a, x_1^2>a$, case 1 is easy; for case 2, show $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing, and find a upper bound depending on a (make a guess, then prove by induction), these 2 conditions imply the sequence must converge to some $L$, then solve the  cubic equation for L, you will have 3 roots, 1 +ve, 1 -ve, the other is 0, choose the +ve one, because the sequence is increasing and >0. Case 3 is similar, but monotonically decreasing.